# javascript push not working properly in node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

```
   client.on("joinRoom", function(id) {//this id is roomid user wants to join
      room = new Room(roomid, client.id);
      rooms[roomid] = room;
      client.leave(roomid);//this is users own roomid which he leaves to join other room.
      room.addPerson(client.id);//adding person to the room's people array using his id, not his roomid.
      console.log(rooms[id].people);//list of people in room.
});
```

Here is my Room

```
function Room(roomid, owner) {
    this.roomid = roomid;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.people = [];
};
Room.prototype.addPerson = function(personID) {
    this.people.push(personID);
};
module.exports = Room;
```

But i get only one user in people array which is user ownid

```
[ 'vYDNfK4VPchHFwXQPDiI' ]
```

Why it is not able to push other people id into array.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new room on every request. Check if the room for the id already exists before creating it -

```
client.on("joinRoom", function(id) {//this id is roomid user wants to join
      if(!rooms[id]) room[id] = new Room(id, client.id);
      client.leave(id);//this is users own roomid which he leaves to join other room.
      room.addPerson(client.id);//adding person to the room's people array using his id, not his roomid.
      console.log(rooms[id].people);//list of people in room.
});
```

Comment: I have put room = new Room(roomid, client.id);
      rooms[roomid] = room; outside client.on("joinRoom"....I have just showed you here that how i created that room.

Comment: You don't need to put it outside, because it has to be created for the first time. But you need to put a check so that you don't keep reassigning it. Also, you are getting 'id' as function input, but using roomid everywhere inside the anonymous function. There is no problem whatsoever with push function.